# C# WPF ListBoxItem задать ControlTemplate для каждого ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Как задать ControlTemplate для каждого ListBoxItem внутри ListBox?
Например я могу в XAML добавить ListBoxItem внутри ListBox и задать ему Template но если мне нужно забиндить указав ItemSource и чтобы все ListBoxItem внутри имели один ControlTemplate как указать?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```